# html list elements based on array length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of cars in a backend, whose length is user defined. So if the user selects 3 cars the array will have 3 elements in it. I want to display certain aspects of the cars in html elements in a list. The array is javascript based.

Something to this effect:

```
<ul class="cars">
   <li>
      <img src=car[0].imageUrl>
      <h3>#{car[0].name}</h3>
      <span id="brand">#{car[0].brand}</span>
      <p>#{car[0].desc}</p>
   </li>
    <!--->until car[car.length-1]<!--->
</ul>
```

I'm new, so if I didn't explain something clearly. I apologize, I'll do my best to clarify.

EDIT: Thanks for all the feedback, Ended up using ng-repeat. I realize there are multiple ways to skin this cat. My goal was to get multiple answers. Next time I know to ask for one specific solution.

Comment: I think you probably need to read a bit more about web development, tutorials, youtube, etc, and get a basic working knowledge.

Comment: You should wrap your javascript code within <script> tags else it will not work. Read these tutorials for HTML http://www.w3schools.com/js/ and for JS http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: This is just a segment of the html file. It displays the information I want, but I wanted to know if there was a way to do this with a loop of some sort

Comment: At least tell us for what framework is that template. That code is not just HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: I'm writing in jade, I tried to translate it back to html. Not sure if I did that 100% accurately

Comment: just to be clear this is being done in angular? If so this is a very simple `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using angular full html syntax I will assume you have an array `$scope.cars` in controller.

You would use `ng-repeat` to create your list:

```
<ul class="cars">
   <li ng-repeat="car in cars">
      <img ng-src="car.imageUrl">
      <h3>{{car.name}}</h3>
      <span id="brand">{{car.brand}}</span>
      <p>{{car.desc}}</p>
   </li>   
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl ! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I'm genuinely not trying to be mean...but you are soooooooooo amazingly far off that it's hard to even know where to begin. That is not even how javascript code gets executed. None of that will even run, the browser will just assume it's weird text you want shown.

JS is not something that you just stick wherever in your HTML code and have it output like you have it. It runs separate from the HTML (which is NOT a scripting language). And I have no idea where you got the #{} stuff from. Is that some sort of misunderstanding with CSS styles?

```
<ul id="cars"></ul>
<script>
    var car = [
        {imageUrl:'url1',name:'name1',brand:'brand1',desc:'desc1'},
        {imageUrl:'url2',name:'name2',brand:'brand2',desc:'desc2'},
        {imageUrl:'url3',name:'name3',brand:'brand3',desc:'desc3'},
        {imageUrl:'url4',name:'name4',brand:'brand4',desc:'desc4'}
    ]; // don't know where your array comes from, had to make my own

    var carsElem = document.getElementById('cars');
    var htmlOut = '';
    for (i=0; i<car.length; i++)
        htmlOut += '<li><img src="'+car[i].imageUrl+'"><h3>'+car[i].name+'</h3><span class="brand">'+car[i].brand+'</span><p>'+car[i].desc+'</p></li>';
    carsElem.innerHTML = htmlOut;
</script>
```

As you can see this looks **nothing** like what you put. What you put is not even any form of HTML/JavaScript. If you want to be able to do this sort of thing you're going to have to start at ground zero and learn from "hello world".

Comment: based on angular tag...this answer is the one that is extremely far off the mark. OP's code is very close to being a workable angular template

Comment: even if it's not angular,  jade is a  templating engine run in javascript on node servers

Comment: @charlietfl - It has a jQuery tag too...doesn't seem to mean much. The question simply says he has a javascript array and wants to put it in HTML elements and was tagged to show up in the "javascript" section of the site. The first mention of jade was made in a comment and after my answer.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified that the code snippet was from my html file. I appreciate the help.